# Label is too long in Doughnut Chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I try to display a [Doughnut Chart](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/doughnut.html) with the chart.js library.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ['long long long long long long title', 'title', 'title', 'title', 'title'],
            datasets: [{
                data: [54,36,12,4,20],
                backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
            }]
        },
        options: {
          legend: {
              display: true,
              position: 'bottom',
              labels: {
                  fontColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                  fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fullWidth: true,
                  padding:15
                }
              }
        }
});
```

I have the problem that for a certain page width the `long long ... long title` is not correctly displayed.

In some situations it looks like this:

[image]

Is there anything I can do so that the long label will be shown in multiple lines instead of leaving the box?

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9fc5evjk/)
https://jsfiddle.net/9fc5evjk/

Comment: @Craicerjack there exists a solution but that solution does not work for every chart type(https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/2704). Although your referenced question is very similar its asking for radar chart, where this is about doughnut chart

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported "out of the box" by chart.js. You will need to determine what solution works best for you and implement it yourself. You will need to provide modified strings to the instantiation of `myChart`.

You could automatically truncate a title after X number of characters, maybe add a '...' to the end when it happens to make it obvious when a title has been shortened.